# With python, how to do looped "unlimited" range indexing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having a list or str, like this:

```
value = 'Water'
```

Indexing with i=4 `value[4]` gives me 'r'.

How can i turn my indexing to use larger (unlimited range) values like `16` to get 'r', or `40` for 'W'?

Comment: What purpose does using 40 for "W" serve? What should 39 return? What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Are you trying to create a loop that simply goes back to the start of a string after reaching the end?

Comment: @BryanOakley some function that needs rarely addressing in lower size value to avoid creating repeated version of that value. related to encryption. One-liner solution was asked in this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use modulus:

```
>>> value = "Water"
>>> value[16 % len(value)]
'a'
>>> value[40 % len(value)]
'W'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use remainder operator:

```
>>> value = 'Water'
>>> value[16%len(value)]
'a'
>>> value[40%len(value)]
'W'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `itertools` solution, but it's not pretty...

```
>>> import itertools
>>> value = 'Water'
>>> next(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(value), 16))
'a'
>>> next(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(value), 40))
'W'
```

[`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) will repeat your input iterable (`'Water'` in this case) infinitely. [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) allows you to slice an iterable as if it were a `list`. Calling [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) once just returns the first value from the slice.